# How can I inline the label with the input horizontally and the inputs vertically

Tags: css, html

My problem is that I cannot inline the label with the input horizontally and the inputs vertically

I wish to have an output like this:

[image]

But I'm using a table on this. Now I want not to use table but I dont know how to do it. I try  to make but it is very wrong.

Here's my css

```
   article#login, article#register {
    padding:5px 0 5px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

And here's my html

```
<section id="siteContent" class="tabs">
    <h1>Section</h1>
    <article id="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label>E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password">
        <input type="button" value="Login">
    </article>
    <article id="register">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text">
        <label>E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password">
        <label>Re-type:</label>
        <input type="password">
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: I'd just use `div`s and `inline-block` spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>As far as I am aware, there is no true way to achieve horizontal and vertical alignment without a table.</strike>(I was just proven wrong by @TimMedora)  However, if you want your input boxes to appear on the same line as the label, you're going to want to adjust their size.  They are currently larger than your box, and thus get pushed around by the other elements.  Once you do this however, you'll still want to apply the following css(or something similar) so your elements stay on their individual lines:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YWyar/)

Comment: Setting a width on the labels cleans this approach up considerably: http://jsfiddle.net/YWyar/1/

Comment: @TimMedora Thanks for that note.  I've edited my post to strike through the inaccurate information.  No reason to include anything further with that comment of yours.  Thanks, heh.

Comment: @TimMedora Yes it works, got only one problem how can i put the button to the buttom of the input and align it right to be able to inline with the input vertically? thanks http://jsfiddle.net/YWyar/1/

Comment: And here is something I came up with as well, as my interpretation of your question: http://jsfiddle.net/YWyar/3/

Comment: How can I inline the button to inputs right side vertically? Here's my JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/YWyar/5/

Comment: @BrainedWashed Adding in `margin-right: 91px;` seemed to do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/YWyar/6/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just wrap your `label` and `input` inside a `p` tag like this

```
<article id="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    <p>
        <label>E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email">
    </p>

    <p>   
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password">
    </p>       
        <input type="button" value="Login">
    </article>​
```

And then using `CSS` fix the alignment.

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mZXf6/)**

I hope it helps.